# How to make nested underbraces (or overbraces) appear in a custom order?

Tags: underbrace, overbrace

I need to nest a couple of underbraces. It works perfectly fine if nested inside-out:

```
\[
  \underbrace{2 + \underbrace{2 * 2}}
\]
```

yields:

[image: expression / short brace / long brace]

However, I would rather like to have it outside-in, something like this: (pardon my art)

[image: expression / long brace / short brace]

How can I order those braces this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
\underbrace{2+2\cdot2} \\
\underbrace{\hphantom{2\cdot2}}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry, but I can't stand multiplication denoted with an asterisk.